# apt pinning when two packages have very similar version numbers

Tags: ubuntu, apt, pinning

I have a `precise` installation, but I am also getting packages from `quantal` and `raring`. My problem is with the `linux-image-*` packages.

I want to run the 3.5 kernel, and to keep track of the latest kernel in that series I want `linux-image-generic` from `quantal`. It wants to install `linux-image-3.5.0-xx-generic` and `linux-image-extra-3.5.0-xx-generic`. So far so good.

My problem is that `precise-updates` *also* contains a `linux-image-3.5.0-xx-generic` with the same version number plus an added `~precise1`. This one is not compatible with `linux-image-extras-3.5.0-xx-generic`, because the package layouts in `precise` and `quantal` are different -- `quantal` splits the modules into a main package and an `-extras` package, but in `precise` there's only one big main package.

Now, I have tried pinning kernels to `quantal` with these lines:

```
Package: linux-image-3.5*
Pin: release n=quantal
Pin-Priority: 600

Package: linux-image-generic
Pin: release n=quantal
Pin-Priority: 600
```

I thought this would have solved the problem and prioritized e.g. `quantal`'s `3.5.0-21.32` over `precise`'s `3.5.0-21.32~precise1`. But it seems that the pinning in fact finally resolves to versions, not archives (the `Pin` seems to be merely a filter for selecting a version number), and these two versions are considered in some sense the same version. In the end, it always prefers the wrong package.

```
$ apt-cache policy linux-image-3.5.0-21-generic
linux-image-3.5.0-21-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.5.0-21.32~precise1
  Package pin: 3.5.0-21.32
  Version table:
     3.5.0-21.32 600
        500 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.5.0-21.32~precise1 600
        990 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        990 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
```

Even if a provide a specific `Pin` for `precise` and set it to, say `-1`, the `precise` package "hijacks" the `quantal` package's pinning.

Am I guessing correctly what's behind this confusion? Is there any way to fix this, or am I going to have to literally specify `apt-get install linux-image-3.5.0-21-generic/quantal`* every time, like I do now to work around this? This makes the use of the meta-package slightly useless, merely a lookup mechanism for a manual install.

Of course, removing `precise-updates` from the equation would work, but then I would prefer continuing to specify the archive.

* Why does this work, when the pinning doesn't? I thought they both used the same mechanism -- that the `/blah` temporarily sets prio `990` for a particular version. Odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best workaround is to run `apt-get -t quantal install linux-image-generic`. The `-t` priority setting seems to work differently than the pinning preferences are able to, and correctly picks the `quantal` version over the `precise` version.